# I Pass my life + (helping others or by helping others)

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I hear both the expressions:

1. **I am passing my life helping others.**
2. **I am passing my life by helping others.**

Do the both carry equivalent meaning ?
Please explain.

Comment: **Pass my time**, or **Pass the time** is much more common.   Saying "Pass my life" is not wrong, but it's unusual.   If you say "Pass the **_time_**", then either sentence sounds fine in American English.

Comment: But which is grammartical?

Comment: @whiskeychief Are you sure that the use of the preposition "by" is correct?

Comment: "By" in "Pass the time **by** doing something" is fine. [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pass-the-time)   You can also leave it out without a problem.   You can also "spend time" without by.. "I've spent many years building..." [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/spend).

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct and they both mean the same thing.

However, I would use **"spending"** or **"living"** instead of **"passing"**.

In this context, **"passing"** actually makes *me* uncomfortable - I cannot explain why. Maybe another friend can help. Guess: similarity with "to pass away".

As **@whiskeychief** point out in the comments:

> You can “pass the time”, “pass the hours” or “pass the summer”, but I don’t think you can “pass your life.” It’s not idiomatic.

Comment: You can “pass the time”, “pass the hours” or “pass the summer”, but I don’t think you can “pass your life.” It’s not idiomatic.